# Generic method to copy a list into a list of lists in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I'm trying to create a method **as much generic as possible** to copy a List into a List of Lists. I've tried with this one:

```
public static <E> void addToMatrix(List<E> list, List<List<? extends E>> matrix) {
    matrix.add(list);
}
```

Here is the main I've used to test the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List< List<? extends Number> > matrix = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

    addToMatrix(list, matrix);
}
```

Why it is not working ?
How can I do this in a proper way without changing the logic of the method ?

Comment: Is there an issue you're having with the current method?

Comment: I'm getting the following error on compile time:


The method addToMatrix(List<E>, List<List<? extends E>>) in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (List<Integer>, List<List<? extends Number>>)

Comment: Why do you need a method? Calling `matrix.add(list)` directly seems to do what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most general you can make it is like this (replace "E" with "? extends E" in the first List parameter):

```
public static <E> void addToMatrix(List<? extends E> list, List<List<? extends E>> matrix)
{
    matrix.add(list);
}
```

This compiles and allows your method to accept any subtypes of E (including Integer and another subtype of Number).

Comment: Could you please explain why it is working, and what is wrong with my implementation ?

Comment: @AleksandarStojkovski when you put in "? extends E" you are telling your program to expect a subtype of E. In your case, you are expecting a subtype of Number. But then when you are also requesting to initiate a list of integer (List<Integer>) the compiler gets confused, since it assigns Integer to E and then expects one of E's subtypes in List<List<? extends E>>. Problem is that a subtype of Number (as in "? extends Number") will not necessarily be a subtype of Integer too, so the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your method definition to:

```
public static <E> void addToMatrix(List<? extends E> list, List<List<? extends E>> matrix) {
    matrix.add(list); 
}
```

since the `add` API for `List<E>` expects the argument `E e` which in your case is `list` of type `List<? extends E>`.

Comment: This seems to work. Could you please explain why it is working, and what is wrong with my implementation ?

Comment: @AleksandarStojkovski have added the details of what the `List.add` API contracts are.